# error while displaying image using php

Tags: php

so i am resizing my images using the following function.

```
<?php
    $get_w = $_GET['w'];
    $get_h = $_GET['h'];
    $image = $_GET['img'];
    list($width, $height) = getimagesize($image);
    $new_width = $get_w;
    $new_height = $get_h;
    $image_p = imagecreatetruecolor($new_width, $new_height);
    $image = imagecreatefromjpeg($image);
    imagecopyresampled($image_p, $image, 0, 0, 0, 0, $new_width, $new_height, $width, $height);
    header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');
    imagejpeg($image_p, NULL, 100);
 ?>
```

so, the code above is perfectly running on my local server but when i ran it on my website's server it showed alot of weird characters (Check Link Below)

[Error Example Link Here](http://studygenie.org/resize.php?w=100&h=100&img=http://cdn.resize.sparkplatform.com/fl/640x480/true/20161220160844989726000000-o.jpg)

Comment: which server are you using? could be a server config issue. When opening the example url it is being recognized as text/html by Chrome that's why you get all those characters

Comment: you might have fopen url wrappers disabled: http://www.php.net/manual/en/filesystem.configuration.php#ini.allow-url-fopen

Comment: @FedericoGiust it's an Apache/2.4.23 running on Linux

Comment: @MaartenvanMiddelaar can you please spoon-feed me on how to enable fopen url wrappers ?

Comment: Are you seriously parsing a full image as a `$_GET` parameter? Consider using $_POST instead.

Comment: This may be a setting on your hosting provider. Do you have ssh access to your server?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are using mod_layout with Apache?
If so you will need to disable it for gallery files.

Add the following to your Apache config:

```
LayoutIgnoreHeaderURI /path/to/gallery2/*.*
LayoutIgnoreFooterURI /path/to/gallery2/*.*


<Directory /path/to/gallery2/>
LayoutHeaderOff
LayoutFooterOff
</Directory>
```

Hope this helps.